# Is there a performance advantage to coding this one way or another?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

I am trying to write this code for readability as well as performance.  In the two cases below, which one would perform better and why?

```
// BLOCK ONE
var DivHeight = 0;
$(".PC_SeriesDiv").each(function() {
    var ThisDivHeight = $(this).height();
    if (ThisDivHeight > DivHeight) {
        DivHeight = ThisDivHeight;
    }
});
DivHeight = DivHeight + "px";
$(".PC_SeriesDiv").animate({height: DivHeight}, 250);

// BLOCK TWO
var DivHeight = 0;
var PC_SeriesDiv = $(".PC_SeriesDiv"); 
PC_SeriesDiv.each(function() {
    var ThisDivHeight = $(this).height();
    if (ThisDivHeight > DivHeight) {
        DivHeight = ThisDivHeight;
    }
});
DivHeight = DivHeight + "px";
PC_SeriesDiv.animate({height: DivHeight}, 250);
```

My question really boils down to whether there is any benefit in doing this:

```
   var PC_SeriesDiv = $(".PC_SeriesDiv");
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keeping a reference to the jQuery collection is a performance boost. [Reference.](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects)

It has become customary to prefix saved jQuery collections with a `$`, so you could do:

```
var $PC_SeriesDiv = $(".PC_SeriesDiv");
```

Also, if all the elements in the HTML with a class of `PC_SeriesDiv` are the same type (ie, `<div>`s), it is more efficient to make the selector be `$("div.PC_SeriesDiv");`

Comment: Thanks for the advice and examples. I am fully implementing it all.

Answer (score 2):

Cacheing the value in PC_SeriesDiv is preferable as Block 1 would require JQuery to search the DOM twice, Block 2 is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Going with the second way (intermediate variable) gives you more flexibility in the future - if you ever change the name of the element, you would only need to change one place in the code that handles that. Performance-wise, I would highly doubt you could feel the difference - internally it's either substituted back as a reference or still very negligible. In fact, it might be faster because you would not need to do a lookup again.

Comment: I doubt I would see much of an improvement either.  But, if there's a lot of bad code floating around on the page, good habits help.  Thanks for the response!